# Magento, configurable product : synchronisation of an attribute with radio-button

Tags: jquery, magento, magento-1.7, configurable-product

I have a configurable product with 3 attribute fields (`Field1, Field2, Field3`)
My need is for the second one(`Field1` which id is `attribute134`) to have a button-radio with two choices like this :

```
<input type="radio" name="revision" id="revision1" value="base" disabled>
<input type="radio" name="revision" id="revision2" value="complete" disabled>
```

In effect, it's not possible to use radio button with magento so i decided to synchronise my own field radio-button to `Field2` wich id is `attribute135`
=> The choice in first attribute `Field1` genereate only two different choices in `Field2`.

So i do the following synchronisation :

```
jQuery("#revision1").click(function(){jQuery('#attribute135').val(jQuery('#attribute135 option:eq(1)').val());});
jQuery("#revision2").click(function(){jQuery('#attribute135').val(jQuery('#attribute135 option:eq(2)').val());});
jQuery("#attribute134").change(function(){jQuery("#revision1").prop('checked', false);jQuery("#revision2").prop('checked', false);jQuery("#revision1").prop("disabled",false);jQuery("#revision2").prop("disabled",false)});
```

But i have bugs because of the standard behavior.
=> Price is not updated, and Field 3 is not activated and prefilled with good values...
In effect, it seems that my synchronisation wich is an automatically action don't reproduce the comportement which is generated manually by changing values in field 2.

Do you have an idea how to correct this problem? What is the good jQuery event in order to reproduce exactly the same comportement that manually?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i have change the event listened in varien configurable.js like this :

```
 Event.observe(element, 'change', this.configure.bind(this))
by
 Event.observe(element, 'click', this.configure.bind(this))
```

And i used your fonction trigger() as following :

```
    jQuery("#revision1").click(function(){
    jQuery('#attribute135').val(jQuery('#attribute135 option:eq(1)').val());
    jQuery('#attribute135').trigger('click');
});
jQuery("#revision2").click(function(){
    jQuery('#attribute135').val(jQuery('#attribute135 option:eq(2)').val());
    jQuery('#attribute135').trigger('click');
});
```

=> I don't know why, it was not working with `change` event but it's working with `click` event.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little lost here but I think jQuery `trigger()` should help.
Try

```
jQuery("#revision1").click(function(){
    jQuery('#attribute135').val(jQuery('#attribute135 option:eq(1)').val());
    jQuery('#attribute135').trigger('change');
});
jQuery("#revision2").click(function(){
    jQuery('#attribute135').val(jQuery('#attribute135 option:eq(2)').val());
    jQuery('#attribute135').trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: You're right, i think trigger could been a good solution but in my case there is JS code which (i don't know why because my level in this langage is not really good i think...) don't allow it... Arrggg... But thanks for all !